# Does X Window and GNOME are the same for Desktop Environtment?

Tags: gnome, xorg, desktop-environments, environment

I just wanna know, if GNOME and X windows are the same software for Desktop Environment?

Because i saw at [this article](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/10101/x-window-system)

The article shows that X windows system is an open source, cross platform, client-server computer software system that provides a GUI in a distributed network environment.
And GNOME is Desktop Environment that provides GUI too. Any differences between them?

Comment: GNOME is a desktop and was started in 15 August 1997 (some GNU folks didn't like that Qt was owned by a company, thus saw KDE as a *risk* so created their own desktop instead of the existing ones like KDE, XFCE etc).  X windows however is not a desktop, but is much older starting in 1984 (version 11 is from 1987). GNOME Itself will run on X windows, or will run on Wayland (therefore X windows is not used at all; wayland having replaced X windows in that example).  They are different things

Answer (score 5):

GNOME is a desktop and was started in [15 August 1997](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME) (some GNU folks didn't like that Qt was owned by a company, thus saw KDE (which came from CDE) as a *risk* so created their own desktop instead of the existing ones like CDE, KDE, [XFCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce) etc).

[X windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) however is not a desktop, but is much older starting in 1984 (version 11 is from 1987).

GNOME Itself will run on X windows, or will run on Wayland (therefore X windows is not used at all; Wayland having replaced X windows in this example).  Likewise you can still use X windows and not GNOME, ie. a different desktop like KDE, XFCE, LXQt and many more.

> X provides the basic framework for a GUI environment: drawing and
> moving windows on the display device and interacting with a mouse and
> keyboard. X does not mandate the user interface – this is handled by
> individual programs. As such, the visual styling of X-based
> environments varies greatly; different programs may present radically
> different interfaces.[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System)

*They are different things (running at different heights of your software stack), so differences to me makes no sense - differences will far outnumber similarities.*